# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.audit.AuditAutoConfiguration

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I am trying to write a small hello world program and packaging it with war. I am using maven and writing a SpringBoot App to do this.

Here is my Application.java file

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class Application {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String hello(@RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "World") String name) {
        return String.format("Hello %s!", name);
    }
    
}
```

While building it I am getting error :

```
    [INFO] --------------------------< PackageName:appName >------------------
    [INFO] Building appName 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    [INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]----------------------------
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0:clean (default-clean) @ appName ---
    [INFO] Deleting C:\Downloads\appName\target

    [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ appName ---
    [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
    [INFO] Compiling 2 source files to C:\Downloads\appName\target\classes
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ appName ---
    [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Downloads\appName\src\test\resources
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ appName ---
    [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
    [INFO] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Downloads\appName\target\test-classes
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) @ appName ---
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO]  T E S T S
    [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Running packageName.ApplicationTests
    17:17:40.487 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate from class [org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate]
    17:17:40.521 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating BootstrapContext using constructor [public org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultBootstrapContext(java.lang.Class,org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate)]
    17:17:40.598 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating TestContextBootstrapper for test class [packageName.ApplicationTests] from class [org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper]
    17:17:40.637 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Neither @ContextConfiguration nor @ContextHierarchy found for test class [packageName.ApplicationTests], using SpringBootContextLoader
    17:17:40.646 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Did not detect default resource location for test class [packageName.ApplicationTests]: class path resource [packageName/ApplicationTests-context.xml] does not exist
    17:17:40.647 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Did not detect default resource location for test class [packageName.ApplicationTests]: class path resource [packageName/ApplicationTestsContext.groovy] does not exist
    17:17:40.647 [main] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Could not detect default resource locations for test class [packageName.ApplicationTests]: no resource found for suffixes {-context.xml, Context.groovy}.
    17:17:40.649 [main] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoaderUtils - Could not detect default configuration classes for test class [packageName.ApplicationTests]: ApplicationTests does not declare any static, non-private, non-final, nested classes annotated with @Configuration.
    17:17:40.827 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.ActiveProfilesUtils - Could not find an 'annotation declaring class' for annotation type [org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles] and class [packageName.ApplicationTests]
    17:17:41.085 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider - Identified candidate component class: file [C:\Downloads\appName\target\classes\packageName\Application.class]
    17:17:41.093 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Found @SpringBootConfiguration packageName.Application for test class packageName.ApplicationTests
    17:17:41.347 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - @TestExecutionListeners is not present for class [packageName.ApplicationTests]: using defaults.
    17:17:41.349 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Loaded default TestExecutionListener class names from location [META-INF/spring.factories]: [org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.restdocs.RestDocsTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.MockRestServiceServerResetTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcPrintOnlyOnFailureTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.webservices.client.MockWebServiceServerTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.event.ApplicationEventsTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.event.EventPublishingTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.security.test.context.support.ReactorContextTestExecutionListener]
    17:17:41.500 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Using TestExecutionListeners: [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@338fc1d8, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener@4722ef0c, org.springframework.test.context.event.ApplicationEventsTestExecutionListener@48e1f6c7, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener@55cb6996, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@1807e3f6, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener@480d3575, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener@f1da57d, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener@194fad1, org.springframework.test.context.event.EventPublishingTestExecutionListener@26abb146, org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener@72c8e7b, org.springframework.security.test.context.support.ReactorContextTestExecutionListener@65f8f5ae, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener@431cd9b2, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.restdocs.RestDocsTestExecutionListener@38467116, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.MockRestServiceServerResetTestExecutionListener@5b7a7f33, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcPrintOnlyOnFailureTestExecutionListener@790da477, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverTestExecutionListener@5c7933ad, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.webservices.client.MockWebServiceServerTestExecutionListener@57bc27f5]
    17:17:41.517 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDirtiesContextTestExecutionListener - Before test class: context [DefaultTestContext@30f842ca testClass = ApplicationTests, testInstance = [null], testMethod = [null], testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [WebMergedContextConfiguration@69c81773 testClass = ApplicationTests, locations = '{}', classes = '{class packageName.Application}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@74fe5c40, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@131774fe, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@7d8995e, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.metrics.MetricsExportContextCustomizerFactory$DisableMetricExportContextCustomizer@f6efaab, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@368f2016, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestArgs@1, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestWebEnvironment@5cb9f472], resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map['org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.activateListener' -> true]], class annotated with @DirtiesContext [false] with mode [null].
    17:17:41.636 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.TestPropertySourceUtils - Adding inlined properties to environment: {spring.jmx.enabled=false, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true}
    
      .   ____          _            __ _ _
     /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
    ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
     \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
      '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
     =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
     :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.4.2)
    
    2021-02-10 17:17:42.425  INFO 8100 --- [           main] packageName.ApplicationTests     : Starting ApplicationTests using Java 1.8.0_202 on hostName with PID 8100 (started by user in C:\Downloads\appName)
    2021-02-10 17:17:42.432  INFO 8100 --- [           main] packageName.ApplicationTests     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
    2021-02-10 17:17:45.008 ERROR 8100 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
    
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.audit.AuditAutoConfiguration
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108) ~[spring-context-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader$TrackedConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:489) ~[spring-context-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:140) ~[spring-context-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:129) ~[spring-context-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:348) ~[spring-context-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3] at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:124) [spring-test-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
        at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190) [spring-test-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
        at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132) [spring-test-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:244) [spring-test-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:138) [spring-test-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:350) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.0.jar:5.7.0]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:355) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.0.jar:5.7.0]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$7(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:350) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.0.jar:5.7.0]
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
        at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1382) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
        at java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
        at java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:743) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
        at java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:742) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:349) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.0.jar:5.7.0]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:270) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.0.jar:5.7.0]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:269) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.0.jar:5.7.0]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$2(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:259) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.0.jar:5.7.0]
        at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$3(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:258) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.0.jar:5.7.0]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.0.jar:5.7.0]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:101) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.0.jar:5.7.0]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:100) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.0.jar:5.7.0]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.0.jar:5.7.0]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$1(NodeTestTask.java:111) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:111) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:79) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
        at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
        at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:220) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:188) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:202) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:181) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invokeAllTests(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:150) ~[surefire-junit-platform-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invoke(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:124) ~[surefire-junit-platform-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:384) ~[surefire-booter-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:345) ~[surefire-booter-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:126) ~[surefire-booter-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:418) ~[surefire-booter-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@42a57993]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:481) ~[spring-core-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:358) ~[spring-core-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:414) ~[spring-core-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$2(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:754) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
        at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1660) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:753) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:692) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:663) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1670) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:238) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:169) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:119) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
        ... 84 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/filter/FormContentFilter
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:463) ~[spring-core-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
        ... 100 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter
```

my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>GroupId</groupId>  <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>appName</name> <description>DESC</description> <packaging>war</packaging>
<parent><groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId><version>2.4.2</version><relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent><properties> <java.version>1.8</java.version> </properties>
<dependencies><dependency> <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId> <version>4.3.11.RELEASE</version> </dependency><dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId> </dependency>
<dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId> </dependency>
<dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId> </dependency><dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId> </dependency>
<dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId> </dependency>
<dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId> </dependency>
<dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId> </dependency>
<dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId> </dependency>
<dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId> <artifactId>spring-session-core</artifactId> </dependency>
<dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId> <scope>runtime</scope> <optional>true</optional> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId> <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId> <version>12.1.0.2</version> </dependency><dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId> <optional>true</optional> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId> <scope>test</scope> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId> <artifactId>spring-restdocs-mockmvc</artifactId> <scope>test</scope> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId> <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId> <scope>test</scope> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId> </dependency>      </dependencies> <build> <plugins> <plugin> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId></plugin></plugins></build></project>
```

Can anybody suggest what is going wrong here and why am I getting this error.
Help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like the problem is in your Test class ApplicationTests. Can you add the code for that class above?

Comment: @Richie Please find below test class and I don't see anything in test class

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

@SpringBootTest
class ApplicationTests {

 @Test
 void contextLoads() {
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is this:  `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/filter/FormContentFilter`

FormContentFilter is part of the Spring-Web, therefore I suggest you add to your pom.xml if you use maven, or the proper gradle dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

--- Kindly remove this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.11.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

-----Edited Pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>GroupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>appName</name>
    <description>DESC</description>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
            <version>12.1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-restdocs-mockmvc</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: I have already added dependency for spring-boot-starter-web

Comment: No luck still facing same issue

Comment: @SwapnilM it is very weird...when I copied your pom to my eclipse, it was not valid...can you please try what I pasted in the answer.

Comment: I am able to fix it, it is more of spring webmvc version conflict.

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved it is more of spring webmvc version conflict. Found it from Effective POM.

Answer (score 0):

It's can be related with error in application.properties or bootstrap.yml too. For me it was incorrect setting "management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*". I was converting config from "yml" format to "properties" and forgot to remove the apostrophes around the asterisk. It was

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include='*'
```

but it should be

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```